# jQueryMobile alternative to $(document).ready(function()

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery

I have an issue with a web app that I am creating. I have  a function that checks if if the user has input certain data before they can use a certain part of my web application. I've been binding my function to the page create event.

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', function(){
                checkOpenCalls();
                alert('page create event firing');
});
```

If the parameters of the function were not input by the user before browsing to the page the checkOpenCalls function opens up a dialog making the user input the data. The issue is that if a user accidentally browsed to this page and hits cancel on the dialog. The dialog opens up again and the user is stuck in an infinite loop.

What event will load my function if the page is called via AJAX but also doesn't keep firing when the dialog is closed? I've tried `pageinit` and `pageshow` events but they fire everytime the page is shown.

EDIT: When you browse directly to the page (open a new tab in a browser and go directly to the page) I get the behavior I want (the dialog is closed and new one isn't opened) But if you go to the my apps homepage and then browse to the functions webpage I get the behavior I described in my above in the main post.

Comment: @Ross Just tried it and no luck it seems to work when you browse directly to the page (open a new tab in a browser and go directly to the page) but if you go to the my apps homepage and then browse to the functions webpage I get the behavior I described in my post.

Answer (score 1):

You are using correct page event but your problem is that you are using it for every possible page and dialog (because dialog is just another version of page).

What you need to do is bind this event **ONLY** to a certain page. Fro example if this is your page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">

</div>
```

you will use this javascript to execute only when this page is created for the first time:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#index',function(){
    checkOpenCalls();
    alert('page create event firing');
});
```

If you take a look, because my page has an id #index this **`pagecreate`** event is **ONLY** bound to it and nothing else.

Comment: @Gajotres Firstly thank you. I applied your fix and now the event does not fire all the time but it does fire when I close the dialog. Which is a behavior I do not want. Is their a way to avoid this?

Comment: Have you bind it to a correct page? This event will fire only once. If this is an event that fires dialog then it should not run when dialog is closed.

Comment: @Gajotres Yep the issue was that when I closed the dialog I sent the user back to the same page causing the same dialog to be loaded. I got around that by sending the user to the homepage and telling them that they need to set the parameters to use the function.